# Aumentar/Disminuir tamaño de fuente toda la app angular con boton

Tags: angular, font-size

Quiero colocar un boton en el html que cuando de clic aumente 2px el valor del fontsize y otro boton que al dar clic disminuya dos pixeles el valor del fontsize.

actualmente tengo el codigo asi pero solo me lo cambia a los que tengan el id #para, pero necesito que se cambie para todo el sitio.

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  
  fontSize = 14;
  @ViewChild('para', {static: true}) para: ElementRef;

 
  changeFont(operator){
    operator === '+' ? this.fontSize++ : this.fontSize--;
    (this.para.nativeElement as HTMLElement).style.fontSize = `${this.fontSize}px`;
  }
```

el html lo tengo asi:

```
<div (click)="changeFont('+')" class="font-control" id="font-up">A<sup>+</sup></div>
<div (click)="changeFont('-')" class="font-control" id="font-down">A<sup>-</sup></div>
```

Como podria hacer que cuando den clic aumente o disminuya a todos los componentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aplica el cambio de fuente al body.

```
  changeFont(operator){
        operator === '+' ? this.fontSize++ : this.fontSize--;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize  = `${this.fontSize}px`;
    }
```

Solo revisa que el index.html tenga un body:

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <my-app>loading</my-app>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó.

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como "mejor respuesta" para que sea de utilidad para otras personas con el mismo problema.